# How can I draw the outer edges of outerplanar Graphs with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Hello Dear Texexchange community.

I am new to using Tikz and I want to draw curved edges for outerplanar graphs. However i cant push them outwards enough for it to look right.
that is my code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle {main}=[draw, circle, fill=black!30]
    \node[main](1) at (1,2){1};
    \node[main](2) at (2,2){2};
    \node[main](3) at (3,1.5){3};
    \node[main](4) at (3,0.5){4};
    \node[main](8) at (0,1.5){8};
    \node[main](7) at (0,0.5){7};
    \node[main](5) at (2,0){5};
    \node[main](6) at (1,0){6};
    \draw (1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5)--(6)--(7)--(8);
    \draw [->,red] (8.west) to [out=-160,in=-90] (4.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: How it should look]

The edge in question is the one from 8 to 4 in the code it is red.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some `looseness` to your curves.

[image: outer edges of outerplanar Graphs with Tikz]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle {main}=[draw, circle, fill=black!30]
    \node[main](1) at (1,2){1};
    \node[main](2) at (2,2){2};
    \node[main](3) at (3,1.5){3};
    \node[main](4) at (3,0.5){4};
    \node[main](8) at (0,1.5){8};
    \node[main](7) at (0,0.5){7};
    \node[main](5) at (2,0){5};
    \node[main](6) at (1,0){6};
    \draw (1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5)--(6)--(7)--(8);
    \draw [->,red] (8.west) to [out=-160,in=-90,looseness=3] (4.south);
    \draw [->,red] (8.south west) to [out=-140,in=-90,looseness=2] (5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also do it more accurately with Bézier curves.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you! I'll look for a tutorial on bezier curves maybe i like them more! But that is close to perfect :*